# How to pass data from the sorting function to be displayed?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I stored my json object into global variable like this:

```
var getData= data;
```

//and I can append the value just for name property like this

```
 $("#Name").on("click",function()
 {
    $(".the-return").slideUp("normal",function()
    {
        //getData.responseData.sort('name');//to call the sorting function

    for (i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
    $(".the-return2").append("<div class='inside_return'>Name:" + getData[i].name +"</div>");

    }

    });
});
```

The problem now, I want to sort before I display...so I call the function like this:  `getData.responseData.sort('name');`

My sorting function:

```
getData.responseData.sort(function (a, b) {
    switch (sortOption) {
        case 1:
            a = a.name,
            b = b.name;
            type = "string";
        case 2:
            a = a.reputation,
            b = b.reputation;
            type = "numeric";
        // etc
    }
    if (type == "numeric")
    {
        // numeric comparison
        return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
    } else if (type == "string") {

        // string comparison
        return a.localeCompare(b); 
    }
    // etc

    return;
});
```

Problem now is, unable to sort and display data after that sorting function is called..How do I properly initiate a call to that function pass display data after sorted?

I'm thinking to call a function at the end of my sorting function to append the sorted data to a div called  the-return2 like this:

sorting function above
............
...............

```
return a.localeCompare(b); 
        }
        // etc

        return;
display_all(b);//to call a function to append
    });
```

appended data:

```
function display_all(sorted_data)
{
    for (i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
        $(".the-return2").append("<div class='inside_return'>Name:" + getData[i].name +"</div>");

        }
}
```

****However it's not displaying the sorted data!

Comment: any `console errors?`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, yes I just noticed,  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseData' of undefined